# tr command in perl to change the column values

Tags: perl

My .txt file looks like as below (please consider it is 1GB file):

```
hello,12,abcd,xyz
welcome,13,abcd,yul
hai,14,abcd,ghk
```

Now, I want encrypt 1st and 3rd column as like below

```
zzyyy,12,zzzz,xyz
asdsddd,13,zzzz,yul
asd,14,zzzz,ghk
```

I have encrypt key like below

```sh
export key=ETAOINSHRDLUBCFGJMQPVWZYXK
```

Now, I need to apply this key in perl script to encrypt 1st and 3rd column in my file:

```sh
export key=ETAOINSHRDLUBCFGJMQPVWZYXK

perl -F, -lane '$F[$_] =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/ =~ tr/A-Z/"$key"/ for (0, 2); print join(",", @F)' file.txt
```

So, when run above script, the key not applied and second tr command not working. So, could you please kindly help to what is wrong in the script.

I simply need apply like below in above Perl script

```sh
tr "a-z" "A-Z" | tr "A-Z" "$key"
```

Comment: In the perl script `$key` is a local perl variable. You need `$ENV{"key"}` for the environment variable.

Comment: @glennjackman .. even though i used $ENV{"key"} in the script but the result not correct.
perl -F, -lane '$F[$_] =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/ =~ tr/A-Z/$ENV{"key"}/ for (0, 2); print join(",", @F)' file.txt

the second "tr" command not working on above script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this in [the documentation for `tr///`](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr):

> there is never any variable interpolation, so "$" and "@" are always treated as literals.

So attempting to pass the key through the environment won't work.
But you can do this to insert the shell variable into the perl code:

```sh
perl -F, -lane '
    sub encode { my $str = uc shift; $str =~ tr/A-Z/'"$key"'/r; }
    # ..............................................^^....^^
    $F[$_] = encode($F[$_]) for (0, 2);
    print join(",", @F)
' file.txt
```

output:

```
HIUUF,12,ETAO,xyz
ZIUAFBI,13,ETAO,yul
HER,14,ETAO,ghk
```

Or, use `eval`

```sh
perl -F, -lane '
    sub encode { my $str = uc shift; eval "\$str =~ tr/A-Z/$ENV{key}/r" }
    $F[$_] = encode($F[$_]) for (0, 2);
    print join(",", @F)
' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much @glenn.. it is working perfectly

Comment: Hi @glenn. i have input file like as below with "§" deliminotr symbol

"0§AA§XYZ§21032023
1§ 11000007§Hello test, IND§CN §N
2§21-03-2022§00:37:12§ 1725366"

when i apply below approach it won't work because the 3rd column "Hello test, IND" will become as "Hello test§ IND". so we do not want § symbof after test(i think it is consider , as delimiter" .Also i need skip 1st and last lines from the file. do not want apply the key for those lines.

So, could you please kindly help on this.. 
thanks in advcance ,

Comment: This is beyond the scope of this question. Please ask a new question.